# How to set the parent for item in a google form using google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

Im creating a google for based off a google spreadsheet using google script. It seems I can only set what PageBreak a particular question is on by creating the question right after the PageBreak? Is there anyway to switch around or manually select what PageBreak a question item is on? like:

```
var q = form.addMultipleChoiceItem()
var page1 = form.addPageBreakItem();
var page2 = form.addPageBreakItem();
q.setParent(page1)
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Google Forms there aren't "parent" items. All the items are childs of the form.

You could use moveItem(from, to) or moveItem(item, toIndex) to put an item on a certain position.

Bear in mind that the first [Class PageBreakItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/page-break-item) sets the start of the second page.

If you want to put a item on the first page, its index should be less than the first PageBreakItem index.

Comment: Can I ask you a 2nd question? How can I make a page submit after completion rather than continue? I've tried setting choices as q.createChoice('name',FormApp.NavType.SUBMIT) but then when I set the choice it gives me this error: Cannot find method createChoice(string,PageNavigationType)

Comment: @AlexByasse Please checkout the example on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/page-navigation-type . If you need further help, post a new question.